# Cambiar formato mostrado de imput week

Tags: javascript, html, css

mi duda es la siguiente, al uno crear un elemento de tipo input week se muestra de la siguiente manera "**Semana** ww, yyyy" quisiera que la palabra **Semana** no se mostrará al inicio del input si no directamente los valores "ww, yyyy"

Ejemplo "28, 2021" en vez de "Semana 28, 2021"

Comment: Puedes colocar tu código? lo que haz intentado, asi sea un Input :)

Answer (score 0):

Aquí hay un ejemplo del cambo de entrada de tipo semana: https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_week

No conocía este *input* de entre los [tipos de *input* disponibles](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp), siendo así, lo primero que hice es comprobar la compatibilidad con los diferentes navegadores: https://caniuse.com/input-datetime. Actualmente, las versiones para ordenador de Firefox y Safari, y Safari para IOS no lo soportan, habría que pensar lo acertado de su uso según el dominio de la aplicación.

Mirando si se puede modificar el formato que muestra este *input*, para ocultar "Semana", y la [lista de atributos específicos](https://www.htmlquick.com/es/reference/tags/input-week.html), creo que a día de hoy no puede hacerse.
Hay que tener en cuenta que cada navegador aplica un estilo de visualización con pequeñas variaciones: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/week
y siendo un elemento de HTML5 estos aspectos se controlan habitualmente mediante atributos propios del elemento.

Comment: Si, estuve verificando en diversos sitios y no llegue a encontrar posibilidad de ello. Ya había tenido en cuenta el tema de la compatibilidad pero al ser un sistema cerrado no habría inconveniente.